# Progress bar in sqldf

Tags: r, progress-bar, sqldf

I am working with relatively large datasets and I was wondering if there is any option to track the progress in sqldf? The merge operations I am doing take a long time. I was searching for quite a while, but I don't think there is anything available yet? Only progress bars for loop-kind of functions. Am I missing something?